# Link to Report on VF Template

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-vf-component, dynamic-binding, vf-email-template

Is there a way to add an Link to a particular report onto the visualforce email template.
example:`<apex:outputLink value="{!LEFT($CurrentPage.URL,FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))+'/'report.id}">Link</apex:outputLink>`

instead of hard codding the id is there any option to add the link to a particular report on vf template

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!('/' + report.id)}">Link</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: That means i have to query the report and then add that to the Outputlink?

Comment: @user7447 I would say yes. Otherwise how would you tell your VF page which report record do you want to go to?